# blogdown not autoscaling images - they get cut off midway when viewed on iOS

Tags: html, ios, r, r-markdown, blogdown

````
---
title: "Title"
date: 2019-01-01
categories: ["TBD"]
tags: ["TBD"]
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse = TRUE)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

---

**[EDIT]** I put this at the beginning of all my *.Rmd docs and the issue is solved:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse = TRUE, out.width = "100%")
```
````

---

I'm running the code chunk above on my blogdown site hosted via Netlify. When I view it on my desktop browsers everything looks fine. When I view it on my iPhone the plots don't autoscale and get cut off.

Image #1 below is my iPhone in portrait mode. If I rotate my iPhone to landscape mode (Image #2) I get some more horizontal resolution and the whole width of the graph is viewable.

Is there a way to get blogdown to autoscale the images so they'll work no matter the resolution of the browser in question. I have tested on iOS Safari/Chrome/Firefox and all browsers have the issue.

I also have already performed Yihui rule #1 and updated all my packages prior to asking this question via `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)` and `tinytex::tlmgr_update()`.

---

#### Image 1 - iPhone Portrait Mode

[image: portrait]

---

#### Image 2 - iPhone Landscape Mode

[image: landscape]

---

Comment: Just for the record, this has been cross-posted at https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/374.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the size of the plot has a fixed width in pixels. You can specify `out.width = "90%"` in the knitr options for a responsive size.
However, even in pixels, I do not face this problem on small screens. Then, I think this may be related to the theme you used. Not sure though.

Comment: Strange. I am using the default theme. I'd try knitr options, but I remember in the blogdown book it's recommended not to knit (if I recall correctly). The live site is here. https://datalit.netlify.com/2019/01/01/how-to-compute-control-chart-limits-xmr-charts/

Comment: It is recommended not to knit directly, but when you serve your website, the Rmd is knit with blogdown. So it uses the knitr options.

Comment: Thanks I'm using `knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse = TRUE, out.width = "100%")` and the behavior is now as expected.